# Update variable with HTML slider

Tags: d3.js

This is my code which filters my dataset to one year, when I move my html slider I'd like to update the value. I have a variable year=1979 but when I input it into the function it doesn't work.

```
var yearData = data.filter(function(element) {return element.YEAR == "year"});
```

I think I'm missing something, can anyone point me in the right direction?

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyab4kcf/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code that render the chart is called only once time at the request.
You need to store the data of the request and then do the same instructions that you already do in the callback.

So :

```js
var request_data;
d3.csv('http://...', function(error, data){
  // store the data  
  request_data = data;
  // Run update for the first request
  update("1979");
});

// Listen to slider changes
d3.select("#sexYear").on("input", function() {
  update(this.value);
});  

function update(sexYear) { 
  
  // Chart rendering code
  // Do your filters on request_data here  
  
}
```